# About extension of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is there a field extension $L/K$ such that it is an infinite algebraic extension of fields but the separable degree of $L$ over $K$ is finite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are infinite purely inseparable algebraic extensions. Take for example $K=\mathbb{F}_p(X)$ and $L=\mathbb{F}_p(X^{1/p^{\infty}})= \varinjlim_n ~ \mathbb{F}_p(X^{1/p^n})$.